# How can I get access to all language keys in Laravel form the ioC container?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Laravel 5.3 has a function called addLines in the Lang facade the allow me to add Lang keys to the collection in memory at run time.

But Laravel 5.2 and before do not have such a method. I want to add a method in my code that allows me to do the same thing.

I am using Laravel 5.1. I can't upgrade to Laravel 5.3.

However, I am struggling to find a way to obtain the Lang keys as array where I can add keys to it.

How can I get the actual Lang keys collection so I can add keys to it at run time?